# Facebook SDK for authorisation not login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am looking to add a facebook login system to my site where users agree to share information like friends lists with my website, then I can allow them to add friends on my site that they are friends with on Facebook. My question is do I have to setup the whole face book log in for this, the user will still have their main account on my website with my own registration etc... I just want to use Facebook login to authorise me to get their friends lists?
Sorry if I didn't explain very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a login via Facebook on your web site asking for different permissions: for example you can ask to login and authorize the website to 'read' the user friendlist or maybe to post something on his wall.

You can do this using the Facebook Javascript SDK or the PHP SDK.

Here you can find the quick start for javascript: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

and here for PHP: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

In this example, you can see a request for a particular permission (the **publish_stream** permission, that allow your website/application to write on the user's wall): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi

Here you can find the complete list of permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Of course it's only an introduction, i suggest you to study all the documentation on http://developers.facebook.com until you'll find the informations that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use friends dialog
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'friends',
  id: 'brent'
}, function(response){
});
```